# Change disabled color of Swing link label

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I'm using Java Swing linkLabel. When the link is disabled the default color is gray but I want it to be black. Is there a way to change the color of disabled link label?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but Swing doesn't have LinkLabel. Are you using a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 3):

for `JLabel` you have to change `opacity`, because `JLabel` is `transparent` by default

```
JLabel.setOpaque(true);
JLabel.repaint(); 
// not required in most cases, but missed for MouseEvents in the API
```

Comment: hmm .. the question isn't overly clear, nevertheless I think it's talking about foreground which would be unaffected by opacity (as we all know :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported by all Look & Feel implementations, but you could try changing the UI default before instantiating any GUI elements:

```
UIManager.put("Label.disabledForeground", Color.black);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is un the UIDefaults
just print out all keys, pick that one what need to be modified and change the value.
AFTER that launch the GUI

That will change all Label color in your application, not only 1 instance.

Comment: I didn't exactly understand... Can you supply a piece of code for example?

Comment: here is a code how to list the UIDefaults : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListingUIDefaultProperties.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may try this using HTML tags e-g

```
welcomeLabel.setText(this.htmlIfy("<p style='color:#000000;'>Welcome</p>"));
```

where the htmlIfy function is

```
private static final String HTML = "<html>";
    private static final String HTML_END = "</html>";
public static String htmlIfy(String s) {
        return HTML.concat(s).concat(HTML_END);
    }
```